# Redundant LEFT JOIN - SQL Optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, query-optimization

How do I optimize the following SQL? Some joins are being done unnecessarily two times.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.ID,
    t1.FirstName,
    t1.LastName

FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t2.LeadID = t1.ID
LEFT JOIN Table3 t3
    ON t2.someID = t3.someID
LEFT JOIN Table4 t4
    ON t4.UserID = t1.AgentID
LEFT JOIN Table5 t5
    ON t5.ProspectID = t1.ProspectID

WHERE (t1.ID IN (SELECT UserID FROM Users) OR t1.ID IS NULL)
AND t1.BEID = 100
AND t1.LastName <> ''
AND t1.FirstName <> ''


UNION


SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.ID,
    t1.FirstName,
    t1.LastName

FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t2.LeadID = t1.ID
LEFT JOIN Table3 t3
    ON t2.someID = t3.someID
LEFT JOIN Table4 t4
    ON t4.UserID = t1.AgentID
LEFT JOIN Table5 t5
    ON t5.ProspectID = t1.ProspectID
LEFT JOIN QueueMap uq
    ON uq.QueueID = t1.agentID  --<--- this is additional JOIN
    AND uq.QueueID IN (SELECT QueueID FROM UserQueues)
    AND t1.LastName <> ''
    AND t1.FirstName <> '
```

The second part of the SQL (after UNION) is almost similar except that I have one additional LEFT JOIN (as marked by arrow). I have tried creating another table replacing common SQL with a table but it didn't work.

Comment: Why do you need both queries at all? Since you are not using a UNION ALL it will remove duplicates which renders the first query entirely pointless because every row in that query will already be in the second query. Just remove the first query and you should get the exact same result.

Comment: Why do you want distinct on both the queries, UNION by default does distinct on resultant query

Comment: I agree with Sean your second query will contain all of the results of your first query because it is simply looking at an additional table but as a LEFT JOIN so it won't limit your results (well assuming your AND t1.BEID = 100 is supposed to be WHERE t1.BEID = 100)  And I hope you want columns from all of those joins otherwise get ride of them because they are not changing Table1's recordset just adding to it when there is a match

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.ID,
    t1.FirstName,
    t1.LastName

FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t2.LeadID = t1.ID
LEFT JOIN Table3 t3
    ON t2.someID = t3.someID
LEFT JOIN Table4 t4
    ON t4.UserID = t1.AgentID
LEFT JOIN Table5 t5
    ON t5.ProspectID = t1.ProspectID
LEFT JOIN QueueMap uq
    ON uq.QueueID = t1.agentID  --<--- this is additional JOIN
    AND uq.QueueID IN (SELECT QueueID FROM UserQueues)
    AND t1.LastName <> ''
    AND t1.FirstName <> ''
WHERE
    ((t1.ID IN (SELECT UserID FROM Users) OR t1.ID IS NULL)
    AND t1.BEID = 100
    AND t1.LastName <> ''
    AND t1.FirstName <> '')

    OR uq.QueueID IS NOT NULL
```

My guess is you may not need some of the joins and instead of using IN (SELECT) you probably need joins to UserQueues and Users tables  but if you took what you have above you can combine by simply adding an OR as I have done to get the same results without the UNION.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you don't need the distinct as you are using Union and not Union all.
2. Exists is in general faster to search since in most cases does not need to scan all the pages.

So my first try would be something like that:

```
SELECT
    t1.ID,
    t1.FirstName,
    t1.LastName
FROM 
    Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 t2    ON t2.LeadID = t1.ID
    LEFT JOIN Table3 t3    ON t3.someID = t2.someID 
    LEFT JOIN Table4 t4    ON t4.UserID = t1.AgentID
    LEFT JOIN Table5 t5    ON t5.ProspectID = t1.ProspectID
WHERE 
    ( ( EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Users where UserID = t1.ID ) ) 
        OR ( t1.ID IS NULL )
    )
    AND ( t1.BEID = 100 )
    AND ( t1.LastName <> '' )
    AND ( t1.FirstName <> '' )


UNION


SELECT
    t1.ID,
    t1.FirstName,
    t1.LastName

FROM 
    Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 t2    ON t2.LeadID = t1.ID
    LEFT JOIN Table3 t3    ON t3.someID = t2.someID 
    LEFT JOIN Table4 t4    ON t4.UserID = t1.AgentID
    LEFT JOIN Table5 t5    ON t5.ProspectID = t1.ProspectID
    LEFT JOIN QueueMap uq  ON uq.QueueID = t1.agentID  --<--- this is additional JOIN
                            AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UserQueues WHERE QueueID = uq.QueueID ) )
                            AND ( t1.LastName <> '' )
                            AND ( t1.FirstName <> '' )
```